# Microsoft GraphAPI Configure refresh token for long-lived access to resources

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I currently request tokens in my c# desktop app on behalf of a user according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http
I use the following nuget packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.3" />    
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.34.0" />
```

I use the scopes `presence.read.all`, `offline_access` and the token cache as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.tokencachepersistenceoptions?view=azure-dotnet

```
if (!File.Exists(AUTH_RECORD_PATH))
{
    // Construct a credential with TokenCachePersistenceOptions specified to ensure that the token cache is persisted to disk.
    // We can also optionally specify a name for the cache to avoid having it cleared by other applications.
    interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(

        new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            TenantId = tenantId,
            RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
            TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions
            {
                Name = TOKEN_CACHE_NAME,
            }
        });

    // Call AuthenticateAsync to fetch a new AuthenticationRecord.
    authenticationRecord = await interactiveBrowserCredential.AuthenticateAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scopes));

    // Serialize the AuthenticationRecord to disk so that it can be re-used across executions of this initialization code.
    using FileStream authRecordStream = new FileStream(AUTH_RECORD_PATH, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    await authenticationRecord.SerializeAsync(authRecordStream);
}
else
{
    // Load the previously serialized AuthenticationRecord from disk and deserialize it.
    using FileStream authRecordStream = new FileStream(AUTH_RECORD_PATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    authenticationRecord = await AuthenticationRecord.DeserializeAsync(authRecordStream);

    // Construct a new client with our TokenCachePersistenceOptions with the addition of the AuthenticationRecord property.
    // This tells the credential to use the same token cache in addition to which account to try and fetch from cache when GetToken is called.
    interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(
        new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            TenantId = tenantId,
            TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions { Name = TOKEN_CACHE_NAME },
            AuthenticationRecord = authenticationRecord
        });
}

return interactiveBrowserCredential;
```

First of all, I couldn't figure out what is the default value for "long lived":

> These permissions can include resource permissions, such as User.Read and Mail.Read, and OIDC scopes, such as `offline_access`, which indicates that the app needs a refresh token for long-lived access to resources.

Will this token that is stored locally be endless, end by a day, week, month, years?

I also checked the file that was written from the code above:

```
{
    "username": "some@upn.com",
    "authority": "login.microsoftonline.com",
    "homeAccountId": "7f3283e3-f2e9-4070-a3d6-21e621442fc3.cf44c34e-c137-4175-9201-126baf8a9eb8",
    "tenantId": "536c1e89-823c-4204-a466-5c56ca24f873",
    "clientId": "0c9d7e7f-8b0c-4f97-ab31-ba6d0424ba80",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

There is nothing really secret in here (note that I've changed the GUIDs anyways) which is interessting, because I expected some kind of a key, hash or OAuth token.

Is there a way how to find out, how long the "long-lived access" actually is and also, is there a way to define it? Let's say the token should expire after 30 days.

I also try to figure out if there is a toke lifetime configuration in the Microsoft Entra Admin Center in my application settings, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

You should read through [Refresh tokens in the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/refresh-tokens) to understand what long lived token are and parameters of their validity, revocation, expiration etc and configurability.

That said, You can find out from the `exp` claim of the token but NOTE that if your application is not the intended audience of the token, its a bad idea to look into it. In most cases your should focus on just the using the token for the intended purpose and let MSAL manage it.

On token lifetime configuration, AFAIK the lifetime of a refresh token is until it is either revoked by the user or invalidated by the service. The default lifetime of a refresh token is 90 days, but it can be shorter depending on policy. There is no way to define the lifetime of a refresh token, but you can revoke a refresh token programmatically using the Microsoft Graph API

"Long Lived" means if the user keeps interacting with the app for say 3 months without being inactive for length of time that warrants revocation of the long lived token then they will not need to login.